# Printing angular 4 forms - input values are empty

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a standard angular 4 form with many fields that are bound with the [(ngModel)] directive. I also need to provide a custom printing functionality, which is achieved by (simplified to make it look clearer):

```
let printContents, popupWin;
printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
          //........Customized style.......
          </style>
        </head>
<body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
popupWin.document.close();
```

This works fine apart from the fact that in the printouts, the form displays no values whatsoever, as if the form was completely blank even though questions are answered. I suspect this is because the actual value of the input fields is null since I use ngModel to set this value behind the scenes, however how can I solve this printing issue with angular?

Answer (score 0):

As I wasn't able to find a solution, I implemented a workaround: Each input element is given a 'no-print' class and for each one of those I create an element (styles div for text inputs, images for radio and checkboxes) which are only visible in the print mode. This works but if anyone can think of a better solution, please feel free to share.